# Change the homepage in WordPress with CLI

Tags: wordpress, command-line-interface, wp-cli

How to change the homepage in WordPress via CLI.

e.g
I have one page called "Home1" and I want to make that page the homepage. In other words, I want to change the "Static Page" via CLI.

Comment: You can find the solution here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/344242/how-to-change-a-post-attribute-to-homepage-using-wp-cli

Comment: This one is not working. Option  "A static page " should be checked also at "Homepage Settings". To complete this task it should check option(A static page) via CLI and use those lines of code from the linke you recommend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#Listing all pages
wp post list

#Listing all pages with type page
wp post list --post_type='page'

#Updates an option value for example the value of Simple page is id = 2
wp option update page_on_front 2

#Update the page as front page by default.
wp option update show_on_front page
```

Comment: Once I faced an issue regarding a WP site where the home page was showing a 404. I used the command wp option update page_on_front 2 and replaced 2 with my page ID. It worked!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the wp options update command, see the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/option/update/)

```
wp option update show_on_front 'page' --path="WORDPRESS_PATH"
wp option update page_on_front pageId --path="WORDPRESS_PATH"
```

Comment: It is not working. When I go at Customize mode, at the "Homepage Settings" menu option both options(1. Your latest posts and 2. A static page) are unchecked. To complete this task it should check the second option(A static page) via CLI.

Answer (score 0):

first of install the WP-CLI in your system.
   here,is the reference for how to install the wp-cli

https://wp-cli.org/

https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-cli/

https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/

after succesfully install wpcli use wp option command

```
syntax :- wp option update page_on_front {$page_id} --allow-root
example :- wp option update page_on_front "14" --allow-root
```